# PayPal Express Checkout integrated with IPN

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I've got a question about PayPal Express Checkout and IPN. There are few topics on the Internet, but most of them are quite old and don't answer exactly my question.

I'm using server-side REST API. As we can find out [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/server-side-REST-integration/) PayPal Express Checkout workflow is following:

1. I initialize payment using PayPal REST API and I obtain redirect url to checkout page.
2. I redirect customer to checkout page, customer pays for order and he is redirected back to my app.
3. I obtain information if user paid and if so I need to EXECUTE the payment.

The problem is - what if customer paid for order, but sth goes wrong during redirecting back to my application? Let's say my app had a downtime or there was a problem with Internet connection. Generally I wasn't able to EXECUTE the payment.

How to deal with this kind of scenarios?

My first idea is to use also PayPal IPN and listen for every payment change. On the other hand, using IPN I need to implement additonal mechanism to ensure I execute only payments which are not executed correctly using basic workflow described above. It becomes quite complicated. Moreover documentation for IPN is really "weak", so I would prefer not touch this PayPal service.

How it should be done correctly?

Comment: FYI, the REST API uses [Webhooks](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/) instead of IPN.

Comment: @AndrewAngell ok, thanks. What do you think about it generally? I should use those Webhooks?

Comment: Well, my personal opinion is that if your having connection problems, timeouts, or anything else that would cause failures upon returning from PayPal then you need to get that fixed rather than try to reload and execute after a failure.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Express Checkout on the client-side you can specify redirect urls if the payment has an error or is cancelled:

```
payment: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.payment.create({
              payment: {                        
                        transactions: [
                           {
                                amount: { total: "$0.01", currency: "USD" }
                           }
                        ],

                                redirect_urls: {
                                   "return_url": "/path...",
                                   "cancel_url": "/path..." 
                                }
               }
          });
```

},

In the application I support, we use the data.payer.payer_info returned from PayPal in order to process an order, which has the benefit of preventing a transaction from occurring should the PayPal transaction fail in the first place. We also record the PayPal transaction ID for identification and troubleshooting purposes.

Granted, this doesn't help if your application goes down or there are connection issues.

Comment: Thx for response, but as you noticed it doesn't help in my specific case :)